# why is this not full template specialization

Tags: c++

I want to specialize some function over what 'Pass' it is, I'm wondering why this does not compile? (it's part of a class):

```
    struct Passes {
        enum Value {
            First,
            Second
        };
    };
    template<Passes::Value Pass_t> void output();
    template<> void output<Passes::Second>();
```

Suggestions?
The error I received using intel compiler was:

```
 error: an explicit template argument list is not allowed on this declaration
```

Comment: If it doesn't compile, then have you considered reading the message of the compilation error?

Comment: Compile [here](https://ideone.com/EfJcHj). Which compiler do you use ? which error message do you get ?

Comment: Suggestion: listen to what your compiler is telling you and try to make some sense out of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Suggestions?

Firstly, post the error message. I assume you got one similar to mine (once I expanded your code fragment into something I could compile):

```
explicit specialization in non-namespace scope
```

Then, read the error message. As it says, you can only specialise a template in a namespace scope, not inside the class:

```
struct Thing {
    // Primary template declared as a class member
    template<Passes::Value Pass_t> void output();
};

// Specialisation declared at namespace scope
template<> void Thing::output<Thing::Passes::Second>();
```

Comment: Thanks, the error intel gave me wasn't any good when I searched for it, will resolve it when time period permits.